# C#.Net, why does this SIMD optimized code run slower?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, simd

Have tried to optimize my function in c# using System.Numerics Vector for SIMD operations. This is the original function:

```
private void RenderScanlinesTextureMapInternal(int[] minX, int[] maxX, float[] min1W, float[] max1W, System.Numerics.Vector2[] minTex, System.Numerics.Vector2[] maxTex, Texture t) {
    unsafe {
        fixed (byte* tbufferbyte = t.internalBuffer) {
            int tdimension = t.dimension;
            fixed (byte* f = backBuffer) {
                for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++) {
                    if (maxX[y] == 0 && minX[y] == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    //
                    int lineLength = maxX[y] - minX[y];
                    //
                    float oneW = min1W[y];
                    float oneWDist = max1W[y] - min1W[y];
                    float dOneW = oneWDist / (float)lineLength;
                    //
                    float texX = minTex[y].X;
                    float texY = minTex[y].Y;
                    float texDistX = maxTex[y].X - minTex[y].X;
                    float texDistY = maxTex[y].Y - minTex[y].Y;
                    float dTexX = texDistX / lineLength;
                    float dTexY = texDistY / lineLength;
                    //
                    Int32* p;
                    p = (Int32*)f + ((int)y * Width) + minX[y];

                    for (int x = minX[y]; x < maxX[y]; x++, oneW += dOneW, texX += dTexX, texY += dTexY) {
                        float oneOneW = 1 / oneW;
                        float tu = texX * oneOneW;
                        float tv = texY * oneOneW;
                        float tudimensionF = tu * tdimension;
                        float tvdimensionF = tv * tdimension;
                        int tudimension = (int)tudimensionF;
                        int tvdimension = (int)tvdimensionF;
                        int u = tudimension & tdimension - 1;
                        int v = tvdimension & tdimension - 1;
                        int pos = (v * tdimension) + u;
                        *p++ = *((Int32*)tbufferbyte + pos);
                    }
                            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function with SIMD operations:

```
private void RenderScanlinesTextureSIMD(int[] minX, int[] maxX, float[] min1W, float[] max1W, System.Numerics.Vector2[] minTex, System.Numerics.Vector2[] maxTex, Texture t) {
    unsafe {
        fixed (byte* tbufferbyte = t.internalBuffer) {
            int tdimension = t.dimension;
            fixed (byte* f = backBuffer) {
                int VectorFCount = Vector<float>.Count;
                //
                Vector<float> VoneOneW;
                Vector<float> Vtu;              //float tu = texX * oneOneW;
                Vector<float> Vtv;              //float tv = texY * oneOneW;
                Vector<float> VtuDimensionF;    // float tudimensionF = tu * tdimension;
                Vector<float> VtvDimensionF;    // float tvdimensionF = tv * tdimension;
                Vector<int> VtuDimension;       // int tudimension = (int)tudimensionF
                Vector<int> VtvDimension;       // int tvdimension = (int)tvdimensionF
                Vector<int> Vu;                 // int u = tudimension & tdimension - 1;
                Vector<int> Vv;                 // int v = tvdimension & tdimension - 1;
                Vector<int> Vpos;               // int pos = (v * tdimension) + u;
                Vector<float> Tfloat;

                //
                float[] Arrtdimension = new float[VectorFCount];
                int[] Arrtdimensionint = new int[VectorFCount];
                int[] Arrtdimensionminus1 = new int[VectorFCount];
                float[] ArroneW = new float[VectorFCount];
                float[] ArrtexX = new float[VectorFCount];
                float[] ArrtexY = new float[VectorFCount];
                float[] ArroneOneW = new float[VectorFCount];
                float[] ArrTu = new float[VectorFCount];
                float[] ArrTv = new float[VectorFCount];
                float[] ArrTuDimensionF = new float[VectorFCount];
                float[] ArrTvDimensionF = new float[VectorFCount];
                int[] ArrTuDimension = new int[VectorFCount];
                int[] ArrTvDimension = new int[VectorFCount];
                int[] Arru = new int[VectorFCount];
                int[] Arrv = new int[VectorFCount];
                int[] Arrpos = new int[VectorFCount];
                for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++) {
                    if (maxX[y] == 0 && minX[y] == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    //
                    int lineLength = maxX[y] - minX[y];
                    //
                    float oneW = min1W[y];
                    float oneWDist = max1W[y] - min1W[y];
                    float dOneW = oneWDist / (float)lineLength;
                    //
                    float texX = minTex[y].X;
                    float texY = minTex[y].Y;
                    float texDistX = maxTex[y].X - minTex[y].X;
                    float texDistY = maxTex[y].Y - minTex[y].Y;
                    float dTexX = texDistX / lineLength;
                    float dTexY = texDistY / lineLength;
                    //
                    Int32* p;
                    p = (Int32*)f + ((int)y * Width) + minX[y];
                    int x = 0;
                    int lastBlockIndex = lineLength - (lineLength % VectorFCount);
                    for (x = minX[y]; x < minX[y]+lastBlockIndex; x+= VectorFCount) {
                        for (int b = 0; b < VectorFCount; b++) {
                            Arrtdimension[b] = tdimension;
                            Arrtdimensionint[b] = (int)tdimension;
                            Arrtdimensionminus1[b] = tdimension-1;
                            ArroneW[b] = oneW;
                            ArrtexX[b] = texX;
                            ArrtexY[b] = texY;
                            oneW += dOneW;
                            texX += dTexX;
                            texY += dTexY;
                        }

                        Tfloat = new Vector<float>(ArroneW);
                        VoneOneW = Vector<float>.One;
                        VoneOneW /= Tfloat;

                        Vtu = new Vector<float>(ArrtexX);
                        Vtu *= VoneOneW;

                        Vtv = new Vector<float>(ArrtexY);
                        Vtv *= VoneOneW;

                        VtuDimensionF = Vtu;
                        VtuDimensionF *= new Vector<float>(Arrtdimension);
                        VtuDimensionF.CopyTo(ArrTuDimensionF);

                        VtvDimensionF = Vtv;
                        VtvDimensionF *= new Vector<float>(Arrtdimension);
                        VtvDimensionF.CopyTo(ArrTvDimensionF);

                        for (int b = 0; b < VectorFCount; b++) {
                            ArrTuDimension[b] = (int)ArrTuDimensionF[b];
                            ArrTvDimension[b] = (int)ArrTvDimensionF[b];
                        }
                        VtuDimension = new Vector<int>(ArrTuDimension);
                        VtvDimension = new Vector<int>(ArrTvDimension);

                        Vu = VtuDimension;
                        Vu &= new Vector<int>(Arrtdimensionminus1);

                        Vv = VtvDimension;
                        Vv &= new Vector<int>(Arrtdimensionminus1);

                        Vpos = Vv;
                        Vpos *= new Vector<int>(Arrtdimensionint);

                        Vpos += Vu;

                        for (int b = 0; b < VectorFCount; b++) {
                            *p++ = *((Int32*)tbufferbyte + Vpos[b]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "optimized" one takes 3 times longer to run compared to original, what have i done wrong? This is my first attempt to use simd so maybe i have missed something important?

It takes 0.4 ms to render my scene with two polygons using the first function, and 1.7 ms with the second function.

**UPDATE**

I've verified the problem, it is as was said in the comments, loading back and forth from arrays caused the massive performance loss, especially stopping in the middle of the loop to unload two vectors into arrays in order to cast them to int only to reload them back in.

Switching to sse the code has now been rewritten using `Sse42.ConvertToVector128Int32` And there is now a small improvement over the original naive function, another problem has however popped up. Sse will not let me multiply two int vectors together!

`Sse` Will only multiply `float` vectors, `Sse2-Sse3` will do `double`, `uint` and `float`. `Sse41-Sse42` However will do it, but only to return a vector128 long, with 2 values in it.

Its not an option either to use unit, because there is no function to convert float to uint.

Is SIMD not meant to be used with ints? Right now i have to do the last calculations `int pos = (v * tdimension) + u;` the bad way by pulling the data out of the vectors and this negates almost the entire gain. Does anyone have a solution?

**UPDATE 2**

Just an update for anyone finding this post with the same problem, starting in Sse41 you can use MultiplyLow to multiply two int vectors. Thanks to @Peter Cordes for the help

Comment: How are you measuring the performance of these?

Comment: but you have 3 nested loops in "optimezed" code vs 2 nested loops in original

Comment: Also you have declared some variables outside loop scope how this can be optimized to run in parallel? (in layman's terms)

Comment: @mason i measure them using stopwatch class

Comment: Using Stopwatch is not a good method of measuring performance. There's much more to it than that, and you're likely to miss many things that could greatly affect the performance. Instead, look into a dedicated performance testing tool, like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html). Here's [a video explaining how to use it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWmufbVF2A4).

Comment: Could you include in the question the actual performance measurements, that you've got with experimentation?

Comment: @mason i use Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() and Stopwatch.Frequency , then i call my render function 100 times in a row and divide the time in nano seconds by 100.

Comment: @Theodor Yes i have done so now.

Comment: 0.4 milliseconds and 1.7 milliseconds. Are these the actual numbers emitted by the `Stopwatch`, or they are the average after multiple iterations? I am asking because a benchmark with such a small duration would be highly unreliable.

Comment: they are the average of 100 iterations, i also take the numbers after running the test many times to make sure it gets the maximum compilation by the runtime. I've accounted for everything

Comment: Really? You're accounting for everything? You're warming up the JITer? You're running in release mode? Just saying that you're using a StopWatch and running it a bunch of times isn't a proper benchmark.

Comment: This vector code certainly looks slow, using scalar loops to do stuff like `ArrTuDimension[b] = (int)ArrTuDimensionF[b];` instead of packed FP to int conversion.  If that compiles to scalar asm, then a vector reload of the result creates a store-forwarding stall.  SSE2 has `cvtps2dq`, use an intrinsic for that instead of a scalar loop!  Also you do `new Vector<float>(Arrtdimension)` twice; IDK if the C# compiler will optimize that away for you, but it looks weird.

Comment: Also very weird to have what looks like an array of 4 or 8 elements for every Vector variable; if you actually need those arrays every iteration, you're not really doing SIMD.  But it looks like some of them are unused, like `ArroneOneW` for example is only allocated, never used.  Your code is pretty messy, hard to follow what work actually needs to happen vs. what's just inefficiency.

Comment: The scalar code looks pretty straightforward except for the data-dependent output positions, like `tudimension & tdimension - 1;`.  Looks like your vector code has to manually scatter after vectorizing that masking, but that shouldn't be too bad; `tdimension-1` is loop-invariant.  Perhaps better to do full vectors within a row and only handle the ends specially, if that would let you do contiguous vector stores.  But if not, this approach seems ok if you didn't defeat SIMD by going scalar and back inside the loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right, going in and out between scalar and vector caused my problem, pr your recommendation i now use the cvtps2dq function, but a new problem has popped up, can you look at my update? Thank you.

Comment: [SSE4.1 has `pmulld`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmulld:pmullq), which does packed int32 multiply, not widening like SSE2 [`pmuludq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmuludq).  Or if you can do an FP multiply before conversion, that would be more efficient.  But probably not if it requires an extra int->fp conversion to get an operand for that multiply.  IDK what intrinsics you used, since you're talking about SSE4.2 for `cvtps2dq` which is actually an SSE2 instruction, and you apparently got the wrong integer multiply.  IIRC, C# intrinsics let you write newer extensions than needed.